# Service state on resume

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

Given a service that return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) from its onStartCommand:

1) The documentation mentions killing of the service, as far as I understand this, that is not done by calling [Content.stopService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29), but done by the system if it needs resources (or my service could also crash which would be effectively the same - no clean shutdown) ?

2) How can I simulate the killing mentioned in 1) ? The killing is probably different from stopping (stoppping != killing ?) the service using the application menu in the settings, so I can't use this menu for testing purposes?

3) If my service is killed and then restarted, according to the documentation, only onStartCommand seems to be called, but not onCreate. So I conclude that variables of my service are persistet before my service gets killed? Or why does onCreate not get aclled? Or does it maybe?

My aim is to make sure that my service still works reliable when it was killed and restarted. Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

Killing means its process being killed by the out of memory killer.  You can simulate this from the adb shell -- use "ps" to find your app's process, and "kill" with the found pid to kill it.  The system will after a few seconds restart the process and service.

If you are only receiving onStartCommand(), then your service and process was already running and didn't need to be re-created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and was wondering what is going on.

After reading the referenced post, I simply moved my code from onStartCommand(..) to onCreate(..) and it was working as expected.